# Forwarding AWS ECR image scan findings to Datadog and creating alerts

Tags: amazon-web-services, datadog

Was anyone able to get the AWS ECR images scan results into a Datadog? Can't find any documentation on how to do that.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've got it working eventually: from the EventBridge, on a default 'event bus' (*it's important you use default event bus in this case and not the custom one*) create a rule which looks like that (in this example only for critical vulnerabilities found)

```
{
  "detail": {
    "finding-severity-counts": {
      "CRITICAL": [{ "numeric": [">", 0] }]
    }
  },
  "detail-type": ["ECR Image Scan"],
  "source": ["aws.ecr"]
}
```

set the target to an SNS topic (create it first if you don't have one), so that events matching the rule are forwarded to it. That SNS topic can be setup via webhook to forward events to DataDog.

P.S.
I was not able to set a rule for Critical OR High vulnerabilities. If I also add High to the rule, then the trigger kicks off only when the image has both Critical AND high vulnerabilities - which is not OK. So I had to set up 2 rules one for high another for crit., but now if the image has both, then 2 events are generated, which is possible to live with, but not nice.